# Laravel Livewire 2.x is adding query string to URL how to disable it

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to have clean URL and my table was working fine untill I update the Livewire
now my table is adding query string like ?page=2 from page no2

all code is same like before, after searching I have add this in Livewire controller
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

```
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
class ContactsTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    protected $paginationQueryStringEnabled = false;
```

but its still showing Query String in URL
how can I disable this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel LiveWire Pagination issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925996/laravel-livewire-pagination-issue)

Comment: sorry no , I dont know why protected $paginationQueryStringEnabled = false; is not working

Comment: The `$paginationQueryStringEnabled` property is not part of Livewire, you have to custom implement it by extending the trait `WithPagination` and doing your own logic there.

Comment: Hello, thanks could you please help me doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to prevent the default `page` query string being appended to the browser you can do the following:

[WithPagination.php](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/master/src/WithPagination.php#L11):

```
public function getQueryString()
{
    return array_merge(['page' => ['except' => 1]], $this->queryString);
}
```

As you can see by default it adds `page` to the `queryString` property.

To overwrite this behavior you can add the following method to your component:

```
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ContactsTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public function getQueryString()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Here we overwrite the `getQueryString` method that was defined in the `WithPagination` trait and set it to an empty array.